# Authentication to Featherjs using socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

How can I authenticate to Feathersjs (https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#authentication) using Direct Connection (https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#direct-connection)? The following code says that my accessToken is malformed, but I suspect there's more than that to get it working. Where do I fetch an accessToken?

app.js (client):

```
import express from 'express';

const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3030', {
  transports: ['websocket']
});

socket.emit('authenticate', { 
  strategy: 'jwt',
  accessToken: 'what to enter here'
}, (message: any, data: any) => {
  console.log(message);
  console.log(data);
});

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Up and running!'));

app.listen(4390, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 4390!'));
```

authentication.js (feathers server)

```
const authentication = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const jwt = require('@feathersjs/authentication-jwt');
const local = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const config = app.get('authentication');

  // Set up authentication with the secret
  app.configure(authentication(config));
  app.configure(jwt());
  app.configure(local());

  app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies),
      ],
      remove: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

I tried using the secret as an accessToken but it didnt work :)
default.json (feathers server config)

```
"authentication": {
    "secret": "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",
    "strategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local"
    ],
    "path": "/authentication",
    "service": "users",
    "jwt": {
      "header": {
        "typ": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "subject": "anonymous",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "entity": "user",
      "usernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    }
  },
...
```

Thankful for all replies!

Comment: Hi Robin, you will need to have created an Access Token by logging in, or using a custom strategy whereby both have a shared secret that they use to authenticate each other.

Comment: Thank you @mchaffe! But logging in to where? thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @mchaffe! I managed to solve it with your help. Here is the code used:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

// Load environments
const config = dotenv.config()
if (config.error) throw config.error

const io = require('socket.io-client');
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/client');
const localStorage = require('localstorage-memory');

const client = feathers();

const socket = io('http://localhost:3030/', {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  forceNew: true
});

client.configure(feathers.socketio(socket), {
  timeout: 10000
});

client.configure(feathers.authentication({
  jwtStrategy: 'jwt',
  storage: localStorage,
  storageKey: 'some-token'
}));

const payload = {
  strategy: 'local',
  email: process.env.FEATHERS_AUTHENTICATION_EMAIL,
  password: process.env.FEATHERS_AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD
};

client.authenticate(payload).then((response: any) => {
  // Do stuff to hooray here
  console.log('Access Token: ' + response.accessToken);

  // Works!
  socket.emit('get', 'logger', 1, (error: any, log: any) => {
    console.log('Found log: ' + JSON.stringify(log));
  });

}).catch((e: any) =>  {
  console.log('Error: ' + e); 
});
```

I am all ears if you have suggestion on improvements! :) It seems I can access data from the database using the socket.emit method. Do I need to verify the accessToken returned? Thanks again!

Comment: If you are using the client, you should be able to use the client to call feathers services rather than using the socket directly. `client.service(‘messages’).create({ text: ‘new message’ })` this will be sent using sockets, so there is no need to use the socket connection directly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an `accessToken` you will typically need to authenticate with a strategy using `email/password` or `oauth`. This will return an `accessToken` which you can then use for `jwt` authentication.

An alternative approach would be to use a [custom authentication strategy](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/auth/recipe.custom-auth-strategy.html) which would allow you to have a shared secret that both servers could use to communicate with each other.